# Efficient way to segregate data in php

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel and I want to retrieve the data using Eloquent.

My controller:

```
 public function getquesdet(){
    $id = Request::input('id');

    $question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)->with('qtags.tags')->with('comments')->with('answers')
    ->first();
    $i=0;
    $tagnames[]=0;
    foreach ($question['qtags'] as $value) {
        $tagnames[$i] = $value['tags']['tag'];

        $i++;
    }
    $j=0;
    $comments[]=0;
    foreach ($question['comments'] as $value) {
        $comments[$j] = $value['comment'];

        $j++;
    }
    $k=0;
    $answers[]=0;
    foreach ($question['answers'] as $value) {
        $answers[$k] = $value['answer'];

        $k++;
    }


    return array('question'=>$question['title'],'body'=>$question['body'],'tags'=>$tagnames,'comments'=>$comments,'answer'=>$answers);

}
```

As you can see, I feel that the usage of `foreach` loops is not efficient. Using `for` loops might take more time. All I want is to know that if there is any efficient workaround to this.

The **`$question`** is returned as :

[image]

Comment: Actually, using a `for` loop would probably be more efficient, at least when it comes to memory consumption. Another possibility is using `array_column()` - if it works on `ArrayAccess` objects, it may also happen to be better optimized for your use case. But that being said, most of the overhead comes from the ORM itself, so you're not really targeting the bottle-neck here and any possible gains will be neglible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want selected columns from the table then you can use `select()` method as:

```
$question = Question::where('q_id','=',$id)
                ->select('title', 'body')
                ->with([
                    'qtags' => function($q) {
                        $q->select('tag');
                    },
                    'qtags.tags' => function($q) {
                        $q->select('comment');
                    },
                    'answers' => function($q) {
                        $q->select('answer');
                    }
                ])
                ->first();
```

Then you can return it as an array:

```
return $question->toArray();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads)

Comment: this is what i am looking for but i am being returned by an empty array in case of those three:- answers,qtags,qtags,tags

Comment: It's working for me. Please check the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) for more info.

Comment: I had to include the primary key in select

Answer (score 1):

I think that looks like an efficient solution. Three `for loops` after each other gives complexity `O(3n)` -> `O(n)` which is good and should be fast. If you have very large collections of comments, tagnames and questions I would try to solve the problem at SQL level which should be even faster, but for small resultsets this should be good enough.

[Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)